# How preserve color of single-pixel lines when saving for web from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I created this button state image in Illustrator.

[image]

When I choose Save for Web it looks like this in the preview:

[image]

How, on saving for web, can I make the black single-pixel line maintain its black color and prevent the line colors from bleeding into one another?

I am using Illustrator CS4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Save For Web dialog, under the "Image Size" tab, uncheck Anti-Alias.

Or uncheck Anti-Alias in the export options dialog when exporting.